# 2 en 1 - Problemas con if tras registrar en BD + Datos aparecen en Front End

Tags: php, mysql

sigo arreglando mi web deprecada, ya inserto datos en la BD con sentencias preparadas. El problema que me está surgiendo es que a pesar de que se realiza la inserción la web me lanza el if de si hubo problemas en el proceso,
no se explicarme mejor, pongo código y marco ** el if.

```
// tras el formulario va este trozo de código
 <?php else: ?>
<?php 
if(insertarReg($nameValue, $usernameValue, sha1($passwordValue), $emailValue)):?>
<div class="container clearfix">
<h2>registro correcto</h2>
<p>gracias por registrarse</p>
<p>hemos enviado un email a <span style="color:brown"><?php echo $emailValue; ?></span> para activar su cuenta. Revise su bandeja de spam.</p>

// la funcion de enviar email está en la página funciones
<?php mailActivacion($emailValue, $username, $url); ?>
<div style="font-color: red">
<ul>
<li>Name: <?php $nameValue; ?></li>
<li>Username: <?php $usernameValue; ?></li>
<li>Password: <?php $passwordValue; ?></li>
<li>Email: <?php $emailValue; ?></li>
</ul>

<?php
else: 
?>
<?php
**if ($respuesta == 1) ?>**
<h1 style="font-color: red"> hubo un error en el proceso.</h1>
```

Entiendo que debería lanzarme el h2Registro correcto h2
pero aparece el if ($respuesta == 1) ?>
Por cierto, un notice me dice que la variable $respuesta no está definide (undefined)

Lo mas curioso es que me muestra todos los campos de la tabla en el front end, sospecho que viene de por aquí.

```
    //Comprobamos si todo ha ido bien
if($name != "error" && $username != "error" && $password1 != "error" && $password2 != "error" && $email1 != "error"){   
if($existusername == "error"){
$existeU = 1;   
}
if($existEmail == "error"){
$existeE = 1;   
}
if (!$existeU && !$existeE){
$status = 1;
}
}
}
?>
<?php 
if(!isset($status)): ?>
```

$status me imprime los datos de los usuarios registrados en el front end.
No se donde tocar, arreglar esto, ¿alguna pista? gracias.

Comment: No entiendo mucho para que abres y cierras el bloque PHP haciendo: `<?php
else: 
?>
<?php
**if ($respuesta == 1) ?>**` ¿por qué no pones simplemente: `<?php
else: 
if ($respuesta == 1) ?>` De todos modos yo evitaría lo más posible la mezcla PHP/HTML, concatenando todo en una variable de salida. Así el código queda más claro, a no ser que sean bloques enormes de HTML.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, pues por desconocimiento, soy totalmente nuevo en esto de programar, pero te entiendo, intentaré encadenar o conjuntar todo el php sin cerrar hasta el final. Este código no es mío, lo pongo según lo descargué y lo ajusto a mi web y B.D.

Comment: Buenas. He estado leyendo sobre lo de concatenar y bueno, creo haberme enterado, lo que no se es donde debería aplicarlo, aún así por ahora me preocupa más la cuestión que pregunté. Y bien, nueva pregunta, ¿Que significa en este mi caso ==1? ¿Por qué un notice me dice variable undefined si en la "web vieja" corre tan ricamente? Ha saber? Pues de esa parte del código no toque nada.

Comment: No entiendo si resolviste lo primero ¿? Cuando se filtra código PHP en HTML es porque no estás abriendo o cerrando bien el código PHP y por tanto ese código es tomado como contenido HTML. En cuanto la segunda duda, parece que tienes un cierre de más `}` al final de los `if`. Aquí cometes lo mismo, de cerrar/abrir un bloque PHP sin necesidad: `?>
<?php 
if(!isset($status)): ?>` Antes ya estabás en PHP, no entiendo por qué cierras para abrir de nuevo ¿?

Comment: Hola, he estado atendiendo otros asuntos, de ahí mi falta de respuesta, disculpas. Como comenté más arriba no soy yo el que escribe el código, está escrito por otra persona, solo me limito a copiarlo, cambiar los datos que se requieran como la conexión con la DB, el nombre de campos etc, por lo que si se habren y cierran llaves <?php de más no es porque yo lo haga "conscientemente". He decidido visitar otro manual donde hacer otro registro y dejar este aún habiendo trabajado mucho en el. Gracias por vuestro tiempo.